# How to update the backGroundWorker.ReportProgress() through a class in another project?

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0

I read a *.text* file which contains data from a DataBase, and upload then, after some processing, to another database.

This process follows this pattern:

In *View* project, I select the file and pass his path through parameter to the *Controller* project, who calls the *Model* project, who does all the processing and formatting, and then call the *DataAccess* project to save it. (The *Model* project calls the *DataAccess* project).

In a Form, in the *View*, I have a BackGroundWOrker component, where the DO_Work event calls the Controller, to start the process above.

I have a ProgressBar too, which is updated through the BackGroundWorker.ReportProgress() function.

So, how can I tell the BackGroundWorker that the progress is increasing, at every registry I save in the Database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do this, depending on how much coupling you want to tolerate.

1. The View could pass a reference to the BackgroundWorker to the Controller.  The Controller calls the BackgroundWorker's ReportProgress method periodically.
2. The View passes a reference to an abstract interface (e.g. IProgressReporter) to the Controller.  The Controller calls IProgressReporter.ReportProgress periodically, and the View wires this up to the BackgroundWorker.
3. The Controller exposes an event which it fires periodically to report progress.  The View handles this event and calls the BackgroundWorker's ReportProgress method.